# Haskell Use guarded equation to create type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to create a type called `TwoValued` and it contains two values: `a` and `b`, and I'd like to make sure that `a <= b`

```
data TwoValued a b | a <= b = ValuePair a b
                   | otherwise = ValuePair b a
```

But it's not working, I think guarded equation is not allowed here, so is there any other way to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Comment: Declare the data type as normal, then make a function which does what you want, and export that instead of the data constructor - see https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors

Comment: How do you like to implement an ordered comparison among two different types..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are needing here a ADT (Abstract data type), so, first, create your data type correctly:

```
data TwoValued a = ValuePair a a deriving Show
```

then make the constructor

```
makePair :: Ord a => a -> a -> TwoValued a a
makePair x y = if x < y then (ValuePair x y) else (ValuePair y x)
```

Finally, export the module with just the function the user need to see (in this case makePair)

Comment: It's also safe to export `TwoValued`, just not `ValuePair`.

Comment: Small nit: I would omit the `Ord a =>` part in the `data` declaration if a smart contructor is used anyway. AFAIRC, that syntax does nothing else than restrict construction of `TwoValued` things. This has precedent all over the place, e.g. [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/src/Data.Map.Internal.html#Map). There's even `empty :: Map (Int ->Int)` although `Int -> Int` has no `Ord` instance.

Comment: @SebastianGraf thanks! I can erase it from the answer

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, you can not define logic in a constructor. To put it bold, a constructor is used to discriminate between values, and to hold parameters.

You can however **hide the constructor(s)**, and define **functions** to perform the construction. For example:

```
module Foo(TwoValued(), twoValued, firstValue, secondValue)

data TwoValued a = ValuePair { firstValue :: a, secondValue :: a}

twoValued :: Ord a => a -> a -> TwoValued a
twoValued a b | a <= b = ValuePair a b
              | otherwise = ValuePair b a
```

So we define a data structure `TwoValued` and export it **without** the constructor (we write `module Foo(TwoValued())`, note `module Foo(TwoValued(..))`) as well as a function `twoValued` that acts like a constructor.

We can also export the getters `firstValue :: TwoValued a -> a` and `secondValue :: TwoValued a -> a` such that other modules can obtain the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Smart constructors are the idiomatic approach, as others already commented.

As an alternative, we can also use "smart pattern-constructors", which allow logic beyond regular ones.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

module SmartCons(OrdPair(OrdPair)) where

data OrdPair = OP Int Int

pattern OrdPair :: Int -> Int -> OrdPair
pattern OrdPair x y <- OP x y where
   OrdPair x y = if x <= y then OP x y else OP y x
```

We can then use them as intended:

```
> import SmartCons
> case OrdPair 3 2 of OrdPair x _ -> x
2
```

Note that the `OP` dumb constructor is accessible only within the module. From outside, we can only use the smart one.

Whether this is a good or bad idea is arguable, though. I guess we are not yet used to expect constructors to involve some logic. Hiding an expensive computation behind construction could easily surprise the user.